# Sending forms value using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, sendmail

I'm stacked. Need to send value's of the form to Email adress. Here is a html code

```
 <form class="form" id="form1">
                          <p class="name">
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                          </p>     
                          <p class="email">
                            <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                          </p>   
                          <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" value="Got it" id="button-blue"/>

                          </div>

                     </form>
```

Script also

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
                var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //Метод отправки
                url: "send.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
                data: form_data,
                success: function() {
                       //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                       alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
                });
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

And send.php file :)

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
        $to = 'damirikq@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Данные заказчика'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <from@example.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
}
?>
```

All looks fine, but doesnt work. Dev tools says  unexpected token in script, but i don't see where. Can anyone help?

Comment: in which line is the error shown?

Comment: which dev tools? JS? PHP?

Comment: Can you post the complete message of the dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracer, here is the code fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").submit(function () { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Метод отправки
            url: "send.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {
                //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
            }
        }); //Missing bracers here.
    });
});
```

And I would suggest adding `e.preventDefault()` in order to avoid the form being submited normaly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").submit(function (e) { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
        e.preventDefault(); //Added this.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Метод отправки
            url: "send.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {
                //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
            }
        }); //Missing bracers here.
    });
});
```